# Devuelve múltiples columnas de pandas apply()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo una dataframe y me gustaría obtener sus coordenadas en dos columnas `lon`, `lat`.

```
    shop_name                       shop_id  shop_name_en                            city
0   !Якутск Орджоникидзе, 56 фран   57       Yakutsk Ordzhonikidze, 56 fran          Yakutsk
1   !Якутск ТЦ "Центральный" фран   58       Yakutsk shopping center "Central" Fran  Yakutsk
2   Адыгея ТЦ "Мега"                2        Adygea shopping center "Mega"           Adygea
3   Балашиха ТРК "Октябрь-Киномир"  3        Balashiha TRK "October-Kinomir"         Balashiha
4   Волжский ТЦ "Волга Молл"        4        Volzhsky shopping center "Volga Mall"   Volzhsky
```

Entonces intenté:

```
def get_gps_location(x):
    try:
        latitude = geolocator.geocode(x).latitude
        longitude = geolocator.geocode(x).longitude
        return latitude, longitude
    except:
        print(x)
        return None, None
    
shops[['lat','lon']] = shops['city'].apply(lambda x: get_gps_location(x))
```

Pero tengo problemas, creo que las cosas que devuelvo no resultaron en el tamaño que esperába el slice de la dataframe:

```
Mytischi
Rostnone
Rostovnadon
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-a5e10e5c6105> in <module>
----> 1 shops[['lat','lon']] = shops['city'].apply(lambda x: get_gps_location(x))

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3158             self._setitem_frame(key, value)
   3159         elif isinstance(key, (Series, np.ndarray, list, Index)):
-> 3160             self._setitem_array(key, value)
   3161         else:
   3162             # set column

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in _setitem_array(self, key, value)
   3193                 )[1]
   3194                 self._check_setitem_copy()
-> 3195                 self.iloc[:, indexer] = value
   3196 
   3197     def _setitem_frame(self, key, value):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    689 
    690         iloc = self if self.name == "iloc" else self.obj.iloc
--> 691         iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value, self.name)
    692 
    693     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value, name)
   1632         if take_split_path:
   1633             # We have to operate column-wise
-> 1634             self._setitem_with_indexer_split_path(indexer, value, name)
   1635         else:
   1636             self._setitem_single_block(indexer, value, name)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer_split_path(self, indexer, value, name)
   1709             else:
   1710                 raise ValueError(
-> 1711                     "Must have equal len keys and value "
   1712                     "when setting with an iterable"
   1713                 )

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando `.apply()` sobre un objeto de tipo `Series` (la columna "city"), no es sencillo resolver el problema, debido a que el resultado de `Series.apply()` va a ser siempre otra Series (es decir, una sola columna) y no dos como necesitas. En tu caso cada elemento de la columna resultante será una tupla con dos valores, pero no hay forma simple de partir esa tupla para que el resultado sean dos columnas.

Es mucho más simple si usas `DataFrame.apply()`, porque ésta sí puede devolver varias columnas gracias a que tiene un parámetro `result_type` que permite especificar que queremos expandir el resultado a múltiples columnas. En este caso se usaría así:

```
shops[['lat','lon']] = shops.apply(lambda row: get_gps_location(row.city),
                                    axis="columns", result_type="expand")
```

El truco aquí es que `apply()` se aplica ahora al dataframe completo, en vez de a una columna. La opción `axis="columns"` hace que se aplique en cada iteración a todas las columnas de una misma fila. Por tanto la `lambda` está recibiendo aquí una fila del dataframe cada vez que es invocada.

Dentro de la lambda uso `row.city` para extraer de esa fila sólo el nombre de la ciudad, que es lo que le paso a `get_gps_location()`. Esta función devuelve una tupla, pero gracias a la opción `result_type="expand"`, pandas expandirá esa tupla a dos columnas. El resultado de todo eso es un dataframe con dos columnas que son asignadas al lado izquierdo a dos nuevas columnas "lat" y "lon" de `shops`.

En una ejecución de prueba (en el que implementé una función `get_gps_location()` que devuelve resultados medio al azar, que no corresponden a la realidad, pues no tengo acceso a bibliotecas de geolocalización) se obtiene lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]